# Creating installer from Install Shield project failed during build process

Tags: jenkins, installshield

I have an install shield project that I need to build from a Jenkins job and create installer (Disk1).

I tried to use batch file with compile & build commands in order to create the installer. I also tried Jenkins's Install shield plug-in.

**When I build the project from the ism file the build succeed.**

Both failed to create the installer, with error message that I can't understand.

Can someone help me to figure out how to solve this issue?

Below are the error messages from Jenkins job console and Event viewer:

From Jenkins:

```
ISCmdBld.exe ERRORLEVEL code: 255
```

(I know that it means the files are missing, but files **aren't** missing. I double checked that)

From Event Viewer:

```
Faulting application name: IsCmdBld.exe, version: 23.0.0.511, time stamp: 0x5906b9f5
Faulting module name: MediaBuild40.dll, version: 23.0.0.511, time stamp: 0x5906b4cf
Exception code: 0x40000015
Fault offset: 0x001fd47c
Faulting process id: 0x156c
Faulting application start time: 0x01d4c9c7078311b7
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield\2016\System\IsCmdBld.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield\2016\System\MediaBuild40.dll
Report Id: ed95a877-35ba-11e9-a242-0050568c6dab
```

Details:

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Application Error" /> 
  <EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID> 
  <Level>2</Level> 
  <Task>100</Task> 
  <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2019-02-21T09:27:38.000000000Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>167297</EventRecordID> 
  <Channel>Application</Channel> 
  <Computer>XNY-SW-BUILDER1.xny.rd.hpicorp.net</Computer> 
  <Security /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data>IsCmdBld.exe</Data> 
  <Data>23.0.0.511</Data> 
  <Data>5906b9f5</Data> 
  <Data>MediaBuild40.dll</Data> 
  <Data>23.0.0.511</Data> 
  <Data>5906b4cf</Data> 
  <Data>40000015</Data> 
  <Data>001fd47c</Data> 
  <Data>156c</Data> 
  <Data>01d4c9c7078311b7</Data> 
  <Data>C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield\2016\System\IsCmdBld.exe</Data> 
  <Data>C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield\2016\System\MediaBuild40.dll</Data> 
  <Data>ed95a877-35ba-11e9-a242-0050568c6dab</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you build your default release using IsCmdBld, it should create a subdirectory inside your output directory, e.g. \Default\Release. Inside that directory should be a subdirectory LogFiles, which contains the detailed log from the compilation process, the log file name has a pattern "mm-dd-yyy hh-min-sec AM/PM.txt". This log should give you a clue as to what exactly happened.

Comment: Hi, I looked in the log and it seems it cut in the middle. there isn't error message there for I add the Event Viewer error message. As far as i know install shield crash during build.

Comment: In that case, you may want to compile the same project in the full InstallShield, and see what happens. It looks like the .ism project file may be corrupted, or there might be a problem with the system where you run IsCmdBld (e.g. lack of disk space)

Comment: Its seems that there was an error in my environment, thanks for your help